# bash - difference between two text files

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say there are two text files and I need to check if they are different. 
If they are, I need to make some changes to them and display information on the terminal.

Will something like this work?

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt > difference.txt

if [ -s difference.txt ]
then
    .....
else
    .....
fi
```

I also tried to find some other ways of writing this in bash, and I've found this code :

```
  DIFF_OUTPUT="$(diff new.html old.html)"
  if [ "0" != "${#DIFF_OUTPUT}" ]; then
```

But I can't quite understand it.
I guess in the first line we create a variable DIFF_OUTPUT which works just like difference.txt in my code? 
Then there's 
    ${#DIFF_OUTPUT}
which I don't understand at all. What's going on here?

I apologise if my questions are very basic, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere else.

Comment: Re: "I couldn't find an answer anywhere." Apparently no one will explain every line of code ever written to you, because it's just a waste of time. If you don't understand the syntax, go read the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html.

Comment: dear 4ae1e1, it's very hard to google for {#x} :-)

Comment: Do you want `DIFF_OUTPUT=( "$(diff new.html old.html)" )` in order to make `DIFF_OUTPUT` an array holding all lines of the `diff` output as elements?

Comment: @SanjayManohar I checked and it's not at all hard to find the string `{#` in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html. There are six appearances in total.

Comment: You should use `[ "${#DIFF_OUTPUT}" -ne 0 ]` instead; `!=` is for string comparison. (This is mostly a good habit to get into rather than being strictly necessary in this case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line sets a variable `DIFF_OUTPUT` as the output/terminal result of the command `diff new.html old.html`.

This is called **command substitution**. You can encapsulate an expression inline by using `$()`. Think of it as copying the expression into a terminal and running it and then pasting the result straight back into your code.

So, `DIFF_OUTPUT` now contains the output of the diff of the two files. If the files are identical, then diff will output nothing, thus the variable `DIFF_OUTPUT` will be assigned an empty string.

`${#variable}` returns the length of a variable in bash. Thus, if there was no difference between the files, the variable (`DIFF_OUTPUT`) will be an empty string - which has a length of 0. Thus, `${#DIFF_OUTPUT} == "0"`, meaning that, if there was a difference in the files, `${#DIFF_OUTPUT} != "0"` and your condition is satisfied.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not called "command line substitution". It's "command substitution". https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: Thank you. Changed. @4ae1e1

Answer (score 2):

`diff` has an exit status of 1 if the files are different.

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt > difference.txt
status=$?

case $status in
    0) echo "Files are the same"
       # more code here
       ;;
    1) echo "Files are different"
       # more code here
       ;;
    *) echo "Error occurred: $status"
       # more code here
       ;;
esac
```

If you aren't concerned with errors, then just check for a zero-vs-non-zero condition:

```
if diff file1.txt file2.txt > difference.txt; then
    # exit status was 0, files are the same
else
    # exit status was > 0, files are different or an error occurred
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  DIFF_OUTPUT="$(diff new.html old.html)"
```

The first line saves the output of a command diff into a variable DIFF_OUTPUT.

```
${#DIFF_OUTPUT}
```

and this expression outputs the length of DIFF_OUTPUT. ${#VAR } syntax will calculate the number of characters in a variable